# where can I see algorithms/codes used for wavelet transforms in the PyWavelets module?

Tags: python, pywavelets

I would like a clear description of algorithms in pywavelets for several decompositions (transfo & inverse transfo if not obvious).

Does anyone know or know where to find that ?

---

update november, 17, 2022
sorry I wasn't clear enough : I need to try several transformations in fortran. That's why I was hoping a CLEAR description of algorithms I could use easily, not a set of python functions barely documented that I have to understand myself. By the way, in this link, where would you get the information ? The doc is very light... I need something saying : "for this kind of transfo, do that"

Comment: https://github.com/PyWavelets/pywt

Answer (score 0):

You can find them here:

https://github.com/PyWavelets/pywt

I am not sure if this is what you meant and if you are using this version.

Comment: thx but please have a look on my update nov 17 22

Comment: I think you could also go the other way. As I understand the package provides basic functions concerning wavelets, therefore I assume that there are papers and books out there that will explain the functionality better. Just like a FFT library is the implementation of the FFT calculations, which one can find in every mathematics book. Unfortunately I do not have the papers or books for you, so I cannot help you for titles, sorry.

Comment: that's all the problem... It turns out few/nobody have the references...